who is right for given example
I have a child in the first grade in primary school, the teacher presented the example with text:
solve the example
$$ \square +3=20.$$
I think the text of the example should be:
complete, so that it is correct
I think and I am convinced that it is a mistake, I think that the text of any example in mathematics is very important and must be correct, because based on it the student must understand what to do in the given example. please can you help me understand who is right

And even more so, the square is irritating, since $17$ is not a square. Of course it is also a language issue. I would write $$\underline{\phantom{17}}+3=20.$$For me, "solve"  means almost the same as "complete" in this example.

no no instead of a square it can be anything, hyphen, question mark, circle, etc

Yes, I agree. But you wrote a square.

let's take it as you wrote it, what would be the correct text

The text I would write is: Please fill in the correct positive integer. Since you made a place to fill in.

What is "the example"? If "the example" means "$\square+3=20$", then the question format is like "Solve $x^2-2x+1=0$". The unknown names $\square, x$ are not mentioned.

Solve is fine. We'd say "solve" if we replaced $\square$ with $x,$ and $\square$ is just a symbol. It's a way to introduce variables to children. "Solve" is a general term. We solve crossword and sudoku puzzles, rather than "complete" them. Solve implies that we know what the problem is. Here, we know what the problem is.

This is more of a language issue than a mathematical one, especially at the primary level where too much formality can be a burden. "Solve" is perfectly acceptable verb here. After all, we "solve" riddles, crosswords, puzzles, mysteries, etc. That said, you might consider posting to MathEducators.SE for a more pedagogical viewpoint.

I think that the equation is solved, while the numerical expressions must be completed

Thank you very much for your comments, so in the end it should be: complete and not solve

In this context, "solve" is more common terminology than "complete so that it is correct." So if I were asked this question with "solve" I'd immediately know what's intended; if I were asked with "complete" I'd guess the intention, but  I'd worry that the unusual terminology might have been intended to mean something else.   Notice also that this use of "complete" could cause confusion later with "complete the square".

Who said it should be complete and not solve? You've just confirmed your own bias here, @mathteacher Lots of people are saying solve is fine.

$\square+3=20$ is an equation with one unknown $\square$, so according to your comment, it can be solved.

they are opinions, just like my opinion, but I think that the text is important, for example, I think that you should solve the equation x+5=12, and not find x from the equation, for this reason also for the above example I think you should complete and not solve, once again the equations are solved and not the numerical expressions - they are completed so that the result is correct

I’m voting to close this question because it's about English, not math.

FWIW I just checked my daughter's textbook, it uses boxes and almost always the phrase "What number should replace BOX in each of the following equations to make it true".

it has a lot to do with mathematics, because the wrong text of the example will lead us to the wrong calculation

Maybe it should be: "Write the number in the box that makes the equation true"

makes true the numerical equation

Valid suggestion, but I would rather keep the grammar/vocabulary as simple as possible since this is a question for 1st grade kids.

its very very correct

write or what number or complete so that it is correct i think it's the same thing, and now it's English
